# I am trying to create a constraint / index to provide a latest record and previous records of a combination of columns

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, constraints

I tried looking into the topics on here that closely related to what I was trying to create but so far I have not had any luck. I am trying to create an constraint/index to based on a combination of current_flag, id, and current_year. id is not the primary key of the table. There can only be 1 record of combination of current_flag, id, and current_year where current_flag='Y' and there can be n amount of records of combination of current_flag, id, and current_year where current_flag='N'.

```
current_flag='Y' ID=1 current_year=2013

current_flag='N' ID=1 current_year=2013

current_flag='N' ID=1 current_year=2013

current_flag='Y' ID=2 current_year=2013

current_flag='Y' ID=3 current_year=2013
```

The logic would be if a new record is inserted under that ID, current_year, and current_flag='Y' (Assumption that the insert is the new current record)
The previous current record will be set to current_flag='N' based on the ID and current_year

Answer (score 1):

You can create an index to enforce that only one row per unique combination of id and current year can have a value for current_flag of 'Y':

```
create unique index my_index
on     my_table (
         case current_flag when 'Y' then ID           end,
         case current_flag when 'Y' then current_year end);
```

As you see from the formulae, an entries in the index are null, and thus not included in the index for uniqueness checking, if the current_flag is not 'Y'.

However, this is a bit of a hack.

IMHO a better solution is that a parent table which is unique on the value of ID and current_year contains a column to identify the primary key of this table for the row which is regarded as the default for that id and current_year.

Comment: I agree that the two table solution is the better approach.  The original question smells of a botched attempt to implement a requirement for maintaining record history; if so, separate journalling tables would be the correct solution.

Comment: Possibly so, or a data warehouse slowly changing dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an index on these three columns without a problem:

```
create index i_my_table on my_table(id, current_flag, current_year);
```

There is no way that you can constrain this behaviour within a single table though.

There are, however, a couple of possibilities open to you. If you want to ensure that no one can break your condition by inserting data then you can do the following:

1. Split your current table into two, one where `current_flag = 'Y'` (`TABLEY`) and another where `current_flag = 'N'` (`TABLEN`).
2. Create a primary key on `TABLEY`. This ensures that you maintain your uniqueness.
3. Create a BEFORE UPDATE trigger on `TABLEY` that inserts the updated record into `TABLEN`.
4. Create a constraint on `TABLEN` that ensures that the flag can *only* be N. Alternatively, you can remove this column altogether as its value is known from the table. It depends on how much you trust the people with back-end access to the database.
5. When you need to insert new data where this flag is `Y` use a MERGE:

   ```
   merge into tabley o
   using ( ... ) n
      on ( o.id = n.id
           and o.current_year = n.current_year )
    when matched then
         update ...
    when not matched then
         insert ...
   ```

   Because of the trigger, whenever you overwrite a record that was previously a Y with a new one this record will be placed into `TABLEN`. Your new record will remain.
6. For bonus points create a materialized view that's a UNION of `TABLEY` and `TABLEN`.